# SQL Using <> to look for Y or N but not catching NULL

Tags: sql

Hopefully this is a basic question, I'm not even quite sure how to ask it technically to search for a likely previous answer.

We have a stored procedure that runs every hour and in the where clause it looks for `WHERE Customer.HoldOrders <> 'N'`

Typically this works just fine, however this morning we caught about 20 orders that did not go through the process because the HoldOrders field was null.

Is there a way to check against nulls with the `<>` without adding and is not null?

Comment: I would suggest you put a default value to your column... This would automatically solve your problem... It would be either Y or N

Comment: How about `ISNULL(Customer.HoldOrders, '') <> 'N'` ?

Comment: [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx). Btw, it would be `(HoldOrders <>'N' OR HoldOrders IS NULL)`

Comment: Standard SQL: `where HoldOrders  is distinct from 'N'` Alternatively `where coalesce(HoldOrders, 'Y') <> 'N'` Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Arulkumar: That suggestion is not a SARG - thus cannot use an index on HoldOrders.

Comment: You can check null before actual comparison `WHERE  Customer.HoldOrders IS NOT NULL AND Customer.HoldOrders <> 'N'`

Comment: @JaydipJ: he wants to catch them so he needs `(HoldOrders IS NULL OR HoldOrders <>'N') `

Comment: If you don't want to check with the extra NOT ISNULL condition, you can use NVL to change the comparison value to something other than 'N' ahead of time if a NULL is found:   WHERE nvl(Customer.HoldOrders, '~') <> 'N'

Comment: @mo2: That suggestion is not a SARG - thus cannot use an index on HoldOrders.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Who is going to create an index on a column with probably two distinct values?

Comment: @dnoeth If one value is less than about 10% of the total size, which is quite likely in this case, that might well be a suitable index choice. It also might be a partitioning selection in a large database.

Comment: For some reason I have seen where Customer.HoldOrders <> N'N' and I thought the first N was checking for nulls.  Is that something different?

Comment: @MattC: No, that just signals that the string literal is Unicode instead of ANSI.

Comment: To reiterate what @a_horse_with_no_name asked, what database system are you using? Because the syntax of answers may vary depending on the system.

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2008 R2